# Django: Why do some model fields clash with each other?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create an object that contains 2 links to Users. For example:

```
class GameClaim(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey(User)
    claimer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    isAccepted = models.BooleanField()
```

but I am getting the following errors when running the server:

- > Accessor for field 'target' clashes with related field 'User.gameclaim_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'target'.
- > Accessor for field 'claimer' clashes with related field 'User.gameclaim_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'claimer'.

Can you please explain why I am getting the errors and how to fix them?

Comment: _These error messages are really good._ They already explain how to fix them. And reading up on **[`related_name` in the documentation]**(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#arguments) will explain why they occur.

Answer (score 301, accepted):

You have two foreign keys to User. Django automatically creates a reverse relation from User back to GameClaim, which is usually `gameclaim_set`. However, because you have two FKs, you would have two `gameclaim_set` attributes, which is obviously impossible. So you need to tell Django what name to use for the reverse relation.

Use the `related_name` attribute in the FK definition.  e.g.

```
class GameClaim(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='gameclaim_targets')
    claimer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='gameclaim_users')
    isAccepted = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: It should also be mentioned that if you do not need to use the reverse relations for all models. In some cases you might wish the model relation to be one way. In this case you use related_name='+'. This tells Django to create a one way relation and ignore the reverse relation.

Comment: The impossibility is not obvious at all:  The `gameclaim_set` defined by the `GameClaim.target` field is a `User` instance attribute that returns all instances of the `GameClaim` class.  The `gameclaim_set` defined by the `GameClaim.claimer` field is... a `User` instance attribute that returns all instances of the `GameClaim` class.  Same input, same output: it's the same function.  The "obvious" behavior by Django is to recognize this and to define that function as a single method for all `User` instances.  There's no obvious reason to tie it to an individual field in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

The `User` model is trying to create two fields with the same name, one for the `GameClaims` that have that `User` as the `target`, and another for the `GameClaims` that have that `User` as the `claimer`. Here's the [docs on `related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name), which is Django's way of letting you set the names of the attributes so the autogenerated ones don't conflict.

Answer (score 7):

The OP isn't using a abstract base class... but if you are, you will find that hard coding the related_name in the FK (e.g. ..., related_name="myname") will result in a number of these conflict errors - one for each inherited class from the base class. The link provided below contains the workaround, which is simple, but definitely not obvious.

From the django docs...

> If you are using the related_name
>   attribute on a ForeignKey or
>   ManyToManyField, you must always
>   specify a unique reverse name for the
>   field. This would normally cause a
>   problem in abstract base classes,
>   since the fields on this class are
>   included into each of the child
>   classes, with exactly the same values
>   for the attributes (including
>   related_name) each time.

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name).

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you have to use extra formatting in `related_name`
- actually, any time when inheritance is used.

```
class Value(models.Model):
    value = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    animal = models.ForeignKey(
        Animal, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Height(Value):
    pass

class Weigth(Value):
    pass

class Length(Value):
    pass
```

No clash here, but related_name is defined once and Django will take care for creating unique relation names.

then in children of Value class, you'll have access to:

```
herdboard_height_related
herdboard_lenght_related
herdboard_weight_related
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to come across this occasionally when I add a submodule as an application to a django project, for example given the following structure:

```
myapp/
myapp/module/
myapp/module/models.py
```

If I add the following to INSTALLED_APPS:

```
'myapp',
'myapp.module',
```

Django seems to process the myapp.mymodule models.py file twice and throws the above error. This can be resolved by not including the main module in the INSTALLED_APPS list:

```
'myapp.module',
```

Including the `myapp` instead of `myapp.module` causes all the database tables to be created with incorrect names, so this seems to be the correct way to do it.

I came across this post while looking for a solution to this problem so figured I'd put this here :)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to Jordan's answer (thanks for the tip Jordan) it can also happen if you import the level above the apps and then import the apps e.g.

`myproject/
    apps/
        foo_app/
        bar_app/`

So if you are importing apps, foo_app and bar_app then you could get this issue. I had apps, foo_app and bar_app all listed in settings.INSTALLED_APPS

And you want to avoid importing apps anyway, because then you have the same app installed in 2 different namespaces

`apps.foo_app`
and
`foo_app`