# Django: related_name attribute (DatabaseError)

Tags: django

i have this problem with my models.

```
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=160)
    voting_users = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text
```

and

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I get this error when i try to call message.voting_users:

```
message: Accessor for m2m field 'voting_users' clashes with related field
'UserProfile.message_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for
'voting_users'.
```

I'm actually new to django and i don't get it how i should use related_name attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says, `voting_users`, needs a related_name argument because it clashes with an already defined related field, `message_set` (an automagic property created by django for your first `ForeignKey`, `Message.user`)

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

You must supply a related name argument to either of your ForeignKey / m2m fields to define a unique accessor for the reverse relationship.

For example, the reverse relationship for the `Message` model on `UserProfile` is `UserProfile.message_set`. If you have two `ForeignKey`'s you're attempting to create two different reverse relationships with the same `UserProfile.message_set` method.

```
user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="message_user")

...
# would create a UserProfile.message_user manager.
userprofile.message_user.all() # would pull all message the user has created.
userprofile.message_set.all() # would pull all Messages that the user has voted on.
```

Comment: when i use message.voting_users.add(user) /*user is a UserProfile*/ i get "DatabaseError: no such table".

Comment: create the table :) If you've been trying to `syncdb`, django would have complained about the `related_name` clashes..

Comment: "create the table" - that's harder to me than you might think ;) like i said, i'm new to django :(

Comment: since it looks like you are in development, it would be easiest to use `python manage.py reset <app_name>` to have it create your tables automatically

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both `voting_users` and `message_set` have the same attribute name `user`. `related_name` allows you to define an alias for one of the attributes that you can use to avoid name conflicts.

(Edit: Wrong link)

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

This question is very similar to another question listed here:
[Django: Why do some model fields clash with each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142378/django-why-some-fields-clashes-with-other)