# Django model with multi ForeignKey to one table

Tags: django-models

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django: Why some fields clashes with other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142378/django-why-some-fields-clashes-with-other)

I try to describe models but Django report some errors. I can fix some errors, but can't fix all. Then I don't change it to describe my purpose more clearly:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    father_is = models.ForeignKey('self')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')
    led_by = models.ForeignKey(Person)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    invited_by  = models.ForeignKey(Person) # who invited this person to this group
```

Can you suggest me a solution, pls? (It's error on 2 fields: led_by and invited_by)
Thanks you very much!

PS: I just started to learn Django.

**Edit:** *Now I know it's about restrictions of Django's ORM. 
OFFTOPIC!*

Comment: Error: One or more models did not validate:
member.group: Accessor for field 'led_by' clashes with related m2m field 'Person.group_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'led_by'.
member.group: Intermediary model Membership has more than one foreign key to Person, which is ambiguous and is not permitted.
member.group: Accessor for m2m field 'members' clashes with related field 'Person.group_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'members'.

Comment: member.membership: Accessor for field 'person' clashes with related field 'Person.membership_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'person'.
member.membership: Accessor for field 'invited_by' clashes with related field 'Person.membership_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'invited_by'.

Comment: Did you even try to look at the message, or google for any of the terms in it? You'll find it has been answered in full here.

Comment: For example, see [Django: Why some fields clashes with other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142378/django-why-some-fields-clashes-with-other)

Comment: The onus isn't on @DanielRoseman to solve *your* problem. When you post a question on Stack Overflow, we expect that you've done a reasonable amount of effort to solve it yourself, that you've researched the error messages, and that you've tried everything your research has told you.  While users here are willing to help you, we are not willing to debug your code for you.

Answer (score 4):

is the problem that you have multiple foreign keys to the same type on a single model? In that case, django can't set up automatica backwards relations for you, so you need to specify `related_name` explicitly. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for instructions

**Edit:**
from your error, it seems that is exactly the problem. It even tells you what to do:

> Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'members'

**Edit2:**
ok, now we're getting somewhere. though, again, the answer is "read the docs". from the [docs on using through relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) (emphasis added):

> There are a few restrictions on the intermediate model:
>
> - Your intermediate model must **contain one - and only one** - foreign key to the target model (this would be Person in our example). If you have more than one foreign key, a validation error will be raised.
> - Your intermediate model must **contain one - and only one** - foreign key to the source model (this would be Group in our example). If you have more than one foreign key, a validation error will be raised.

Comment: yes, i know it (add related_name), but it does not solve the problem on "invited_by". Maybe I need to change my model a bit. Do u have any idea?

Comment: have you added `related_name` to all fields on all models suggested by your error messages? Do you get a new error message?

Comment: i added it to all, and the new error message it: 
Error: One or more models did not validate:
member.group: Intermediary model Membership has more than one foreign key to Person, which is ambiguous and is not permitted.

Like I talked, maybe i need to change models. Do u have any idea?

Comment: yes, i read it ("contain one - and only one - foreign key"), but the question here is how I can by-pass this restriction?

Comment: i see. that's not at all clear from the way you asked your question (hence all our comments about reading your errors messages etc). At this point i would almost consider closing this, and asking a new question, clearly stating what you need help with.

Comment: as for solution, i guess you could manage the relation yourself (just using the through table without an m2m field) you loose some django magic but that's the price of more flexibility than is in the box