# How to add created_by and updated_by user to model.py by Foreign Keys in Django 1.7?

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I recently started using Django and I am trying to use it as a configuration management tool for an older application that I wrote.  So, I created an application in my Django project named **configurations**.

In order to completely answer my question above there are 2 parts to the question.

I want to add to the `models.py` file in the project a class to store all the configuration values. In addition, I want to store the userid that adds a new record or updates a record as `created_by` and `updated_by`.  I was told by someone to do the following:

"You need to establish a couple of foreign key fields in your model (eg created and updated) which both link to `auth.user`. Then grab `request.user` at the appropriate time and do `<model>.created = request.user` and `<model>.updated = request.user` just before saving."

1. How do I add two foreign keys to my model properly?

I tried to complete the 1st step that he told me to complete, which is to create foreign key fields in my `models.py` file which are assigned to `created_by` and `updated_by`.  But when I try the following code, I get an error.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class GeneralConfiguration(models.Model):

    updated_by=models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_by=models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated_timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "General Configuration"
```

The Error message shows:

```
jython manage.py makemigrations

←[31;1mCommandError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
←[31;1mconfigurations.GeneralConfiguration.created_by: (fields.E304) Reverse acc
essor for 'GeneralConfiguration.created_by' clashes with reverse accessor for 'G
eneralConfiguration.updated_by'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Gener
alConfiguration.created_by' or 'GeneralConfiguration.updated_by'.←[0m
←[31;1mconfigurations.GeneralConfiguration.updated_by: (fields.E304) Reverse acc
essor for 'GeneralConfiguration.updated_by' clashes with reverse accessor for 'G
eneralConfiguration.created_by'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Gener
alConfiguration.updated_by' or 'GeneralConfiguration.created_by'.←[0m
←[0m
```

Part 2
How do I grab request.user at the appropriate time and do .created = request.user and .updated = request.user just before saving?

Comment: Looks at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1142473/2169114. It's your case.

Answer (score 11):

Django create a reverse relation from user back to your model. in your case both relations have same reverse relation

change code like this:

```
updated_by=models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='updated_by_user')
created_by=models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_by_user')
```

Comment: That seems to compile, can you explain to me why this works and the other syntax didn't work?

Comment: Here is the reason http://stackoverflow.com/a/2642645/3802821

Comment: UpVoting cause it's a smart solution with less code, but I'm facing 1 limitation while using it: "related_name" must be unique while "created_at" is a field generally implemented on many models not only one. I still didn't find any solution to add a "created_by field" on multiple models, as soon as you change its "related_name" from "created_by_user" to anything else to avoid having a duplicated "related_name" it's not working anymore.