# How to Model Peer to Peer Transactions in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to model transactions between users in an ecommerce site I'm building. I want the transaction to be available to both users in a dashboard.

It seems incorrect to have the transaction, and all its details, saved to both users objects. I think I need to create a separate model for transactions, with a unique id for each transaction. Then, in each user's object I could simply save that transaction id.

Would I then simply give each transaction two primary keys, one for the purchaser's user.id and one for the purchasee's user.id? Is this "many to many"?

Thanks for any guidance here.

Edit - Here is what I've tried:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchaser = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create_time = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

However, this gives an error `items.Transaction.owner: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Transaction.owner' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Transaction.purchaser'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Transaction.owner' or 'Transaction.purchaser'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `related_name` parameter for both fields each has its own name, Like :

```py
class Transaction(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'transaction_owner')
    purchaser = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'transaction_purchaser')
    create_time = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

More Context : [Django: Why do some model fields clash with each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1142473/11132419)